# Excel 2010 : Best way to collaborate

Tags: microsoft-excel, collaboration

We have an excel-sheet that should be editable by multiple users at the same time. I tried it with the sharing-functionality but it always displays the read-only message when someone else tries to open the sheet at the same time.

Is there any workaround or do you have other ideas?

Our company's guidelines are very strict, it is nearly impossible to install anything else or change something on the system/server-architecture.

Comment: What is the server technology hosting the file - Linux, Windows Server etc.? I have seen this before when using a Samba server and it relates to file locking...

Comment: It is all Windows. I think they use SharePoint.

Comment: What type of data do you have in Excel? I'm afraid it's not the best tool for collaboration. We use SharePoint lists for collaboration and they work well. Also you can link Excel or Access to it if you need more sophisticated analysis.

Comment: We have a list of data with around 40 rows and a daily increasing number of columns. It contains VBA-Scripts and conditional formatting..

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a management/IT Ops issue than a technical one for you to try and resolve.

If you must - I suggest you open the excel file in googledocs or something (presuming it is within your companies guidelines). And collab like that.

If that isn't an option. I suggest both you and your colleague both modify your own read only copies of the file - then use the 'merge' feature to try and interlace them best you can.

Sadly office 2010 isn't fantastic for collab work out of the box.

Comment: I'm afraid, but googledocs is not possible too.. It's really hard to work determined with no possibilites..

Comment: You should really make your manager aware of this issue, their job is to enable you to do your job - it's not really your problem to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely talk about this in the next meeting, but for now all I can do is ask anyone in the room to close the file.. :)

Comment: I agree, it's very annoying - I've been in a similar situation myself. The solution was to migrate to office 365 for us. This again has to be a commissioned project by your manager though. It's still something you could suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you are unable to use the built-in sharing functionality then an option might be to hold the data in a separate container (can be database tables, a JET (Access) database or even CSVs) and then have a read-only Excel file that interfaces with the data.

The advantages of this are ease of use for end-users as they retain the familiar design and UI of Excel and the abstraction of the data away from the front-end means no problems with concurrency and the data itself it can be better protected from unintended updates (validation etc. in front-end).

The disadvantage is that this requires a fair bit of set up (although you mention you're using VBA already so may have the skills to hand) and may only be appropriate in certain use cases.

Original answer:
<strike>You can make it a [Shared Workbook](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61) but be aware this does bring a few caveats and quirks relating to specific functionality and overall stability/robustness.</strike>

There are horror stories out there of locking, concurrency and data loss problems with shared workbooks, but in many cases they can work very well. I've personally used them with up to 20-odd concurrent users and if managed correctly and, critically, designed with collaborative working in mind, then they can work very well.

Comment: We already tried using a shared workbook, but the error message still catches up.

Comment: In that case I'd be following Big Chris' advice and looking to the underlying network file share as it would appear it's a locking problem, not anything really to do with Excel.